# Indesign: reset preferences saved in file

Tags: adobe-indesign, template

I have the problem, that our indesign-templates for books which we created and improved since around 2016 have some settings in them that messes with the hyphenation (it is definitely not because of the paragraph styles because when I copy/paste a textframe including the styles in a new file, it hyphenates just fine.)

I assume it's somehow because of some different preferences. But going through the differences of preferences between the template and the plain new file doesn't do anything. Maybe there are some hidden preferences? Or something I overlooked...?

So I want to reset the preferences saved in the file to the basic one.

But how? I have been googling it for an hour now but I just can't find a way. One website told me to "simply delete the document preferences". Well thanks.
I tried trashing the preferences using `ctrl-shift-alt` but it's not doing anything. Opening the template gives me the same custom preferences as always.

Has anyone an idea?

**For more background:**

- For years the templates had been filed as indd but were changed to indt a year or two ago.
- what I mean with messing with hyphenation is that it refuses hyphenating words that have an asterisk or semicolon in it. (for german style gendering basic substantives that are about persons must have the feminin ending attached to them separated by some character from the main word which gives us words like Mitarbeiter:innenbefragung and fahrer:innentypisch). I thought that maybe this thing is so special that indesign just has a problem hyphenating it but I just found out that it works in regular new files.

Comment: In the Paragraph window, when you select more options, then Hyphenation, are the settings the same in the old InDesign file as a new file? To reset preferences, you can Start InDesign, and then press Shift+Ctrl+Alt or Shift+Option+Command+Control for Mac.

Comment: It could be some small detail you are overlooking. It seems from your previous questions that you know your way around InDesign better than most, so it's hard to come with suggestions without sounding condescending.  Perhaps you should screenshots of the relevant preferences? I guess you have already checked that *Preferences > Language: German 2006 Reform > Hyphenation* isn't set to something like *Proximity*?

Comment: I actually just found what was wrong. Even though the paragraph-style language was set to German 2006 Reform, the language in the preferences was still set to 1996. I noticed it yesterday but probably forgot to test it. Anyway, thank you. 
Although I still wonder, how to reset the preferences of existing files.